# Two weeks away, no gym

Tags: maintenance

I’m going on holiday where there will be no equipment to train with, no supplements, nowhere ‘lift’. I’ll be gone for two weeks. No, I’m not being incarcerated.

I would like to do something, other than eating ‘healthy’ and running (there will usually be time and space to do that) to keep fit and avoid losing muscle.

What can I do to at least avoid the gains and backtracking my progress while I am very much away from my usual routine?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to the question but you should realise that if you work out all year, taking 2 weeks off is actually a good thing and not a bad thing in which you will lose your fitness. It will help in the long run.

Comment: related: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34355/can-fitness-be-regained-like-muscle-can-with-muscle-memory/34357#34357 - As stated, 2 weeks you might lose a little edge/fitness, but nothing that can't be recovered in a few days.

Comment: if you've been hitting the gym for a quite some time, taking 2 weeks off won't affect your progress at all, and if you really can't relax without doing anything, running and some simple bodyweight excerices (squats, push-ups, crunches ..as so on) are enough.

Comment: You have to realize that this is a problem in your head and not in your muscles. Many people, including myself, get nervous when they are away from the gym for a week or more. Sometimes you get sick, sometimes you go someplace else, sometimes there just is something else that's more important. That's life. You have to realize that you go to the gym for yourself and not for the gym. You won't lose anything in that time. Just relax, there's nothing bad happening to your body. Enjoy your vacation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to at least avoid the gains and backtracking my progress while I am very much away from my usual routine?

### Without knowing your current level of fitness, it's honestly difficult to say.

Since you mention equipment/lifting in order to maintain your current fitness, it's perhaps possible that you're more bulk than lean (or at least, maybe that's what you're aiming towards).

In any case though, if you don't have access to equipment then I think the most you can do is a collection of [no equipment plyometric exercises](https://greatist.com/fitness/explosive-bodyweight-exercises#Intermediate).

That link contains exercises that I myself (as an avid runner and now casual weight lifter) perform in order to maintain decent strength (relative to my body weight) and without needing equipment. They can be done anywhere and at any time and the level of intensity only depends on the rep count and/or speed at which you perform them.

At the very least this will keep your mindset focused towards physical health (beyond a clean diet) and allow for you to maintain some kind of workout routine until you're able to return to your normal schedule.